# How do I send Select value to PHP with Jquery Ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

First of all, thank you for taking a look at my question.

Also, I looked everywhere on Stackoverflow for a solution but I just can't get this to work.

So here's the problem, I need to get the value of a *select option* that is in file `job.php`and send it to `portfolio.php` so I can fetch the appropriate data from the database. Basically when I select another option I want the page to load the appropriate data.

**Here's the Ajax (job.php)**

```
<script>
  $( document ).ready(function() {
     var workselected = $('.work-select').val();
     $.ajax({
       method: "POST",
       url: "php/portfolio.php",
       data: {workselected1: workselected},
       success: function(data){
       console.log(data);
              }
          });
      });
</script>
```

**Heres the Select tag I'm trying to get the value from (job.php)**

```
<select id="select-work" class="work-select">
   <option class="work-option" value="fw">Option 1</option>
   <option class="work-option" value="bw">Option 2</option>
   <option class="work-option" value="lp">Option 3</option>
   <option class="work-option" value="et">Option 4</option>
   <option class="work-option" value="wa">Option 5</option>
</select>
```

**Here's the PHP that handles DB interaction (portfolio.php)**

```
<?php
require_once('db.php');

if (isset($_POST['workselected1'])) {
    $workselected = $_POST['workselected1'];

    $query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM sometable WHERE project_category=`workselected`");
    $rowCount = mysqli_num_rows($query);

  } else echo "NOT WORKING";

    $i = 0;
    echo '<div class="row rowcontrol">';

    if($rowCount > 0){ 
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){ 
    ?>

       <?php 
         echo '<div class="col-md-4 letmesee"><div class="work-content-container">'; ?>
        <a href="#"><img src="img/project/<?php echo $row['thumbnail_ref'] ?>" class="work-thumbnail"></a>
        <span class="caption slide-caption">
            <h5><?php echo $row['project_name']; ?></h5>
            <p><b>Project: </b><?php echo $row['project_type'];?></p>
            <p><b>Check: </b><a href="<?php echo $row["project_url"];?>" class="nav-link"><?php echo $row["project_url"]; ?></a></p>
        </span>
       <?php echo '</div></div>'; ?>

    <?php
     $i++;
     if ($i%3 == 0) echo '</div><div class="row">';

     } ?>

    <?php } ?>
```

I'm not getting anything from this code, the data is not passing to the other file, I think I'm missing something; Maybe I need to add a click event somewhere in there? **please help!**

Comment: @Mit.agile what are you talking about here? You don't solve the problem with this changes. And why such complicated selector? `$('#select-work').val()` will do the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You say `Basically when I select another option I want the page to load the appropriate data`. So you have to register a `change` listener then. Otherwise you only do it once at page load.

```
$(function() {
    $('.work-select').change(function() {
        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: "php/portfolio.php",
            data: {
                workselected1: $(this).val()
            },
            success: function(data){
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

If you want an initial loading too, you can wrap the ajax within a function, or trigger it once manually.

```
$('.work-select').trigger("change");
```

Comment: Hey,

Thank you for the answer, it seems to have worked. I'm getting the data into the file but the PHP output is not displaying on the page but it is displaying on the console, I'm getting the HTML of what is supposed to be displaying onscreen in the actual js console on Chrome.

Any ideas here? last question I promise!

Comment: You have to do somthing with the `data` you received. Actually you only log them with `console.log(data);`. Thats the reason you only see it in console, and not in the page. I'm actually not sure what you want to do whit the html. But for example, you could append it under the `select` with something like `$('.work-select').after(data)`. @Bodil132

Answer (score 0):

You have not defined on which event you have to call AJAX. I am considering you call AJAX when value is changed in dropdown.

```
<script>
  $( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.work-select').change(function(){
        workselected=$(this).val();
        $.ajax({
           method: "POST",
           url: "php/portfolio.php",
           data: {workselected1: workselected},
           success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
          }
      });
    });
 });
</script>
```

If still not work then check then check if you have defined any redirection rules in .htaccess file.

Answer (score 0):

Forgot to trigger `on change` for select dropdown.

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('.work-select').change(function(){
    var workselected = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
      method: "POST",
      url: "php/portfolio.php",
      data: {workselected1: workselected},
      cache:false,
      success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
      }
    });
  });
}); 
</script>
```

**portfolio.php**

**1)** Change

```
$query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM sometable WHERE project_category=`workselected`");
```

To

```
$query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM sometable WHERE project_category='$workselected'");
```

**2)** Keep below code inside `if (isset($_POST['workselected1'])) {`. Otherwise

> undefined index : thumbnail_ref

error will come.

```
$i = 0;
.
.
.

if ($i % 3 == 0)
        echo '</div><div class="row">';
```

***Updated Code***

```
<?php
require_once('db.php');

if (isset($_POST['workselected1'])) {
  $workselected = $_POST['workselected1'];

  $query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM sometable WHERE project_category='$workselected'");
  $rowCount = mysqli_num_rows($query);

  $i = 0;
  echo '<div class="row rowcontrol">';

  if ($rowCount > 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {

      echo '<div class="col-md-4 letmesee"><div class="work-content-container">'; ?>
      <a href="#"><img src="img/project/<?php echo $row['thumbnail_ref'] ?>" class="work-thumbnail"></a>
      <span class="caption slide-caption">
        <h5><?php echo $row['project_name']; ?></h5>
        <p><b>Project: </b><?php echo $row['project_type']; ?></p>
        <p><b>Check: </b><a href="<?php echo $row["project_url"]; ?>" class="nav-link"><?php echo $row["project_url"]; ?></a></p>
      </span>
      <?php echo '</div></div>'; ?>

      <?php
      $i++;
      if ($i % 3 == 0)
        echo '</div><div class="row">';
    }
  }

} else {
  echo "NOT WORKING";
}
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

try to change this

```
$query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM sometable WHERE project_category=`workselected`");
```

with this

```
$query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM sometable WHERE project_category='".$workselected."'");
```